# Symbol's value as variable is void: ac-source-tern-completion

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, tern

Until the upgrade of packages and the removal of obsolete packages in Emacs, I could use dot completion and tern-ac-complete normally. Now every time I try to use those two commands, I get the error

Symbol's value as variable is void: ac-source-tern-completion

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is strange, according to tern's github repository no changes have been made to tern's emacs client for about 5 months. Are you the files tern.el and tern-auto-complete.el are being loaded?

Comment: Yes. The other functions of the term.el work just fine. It is just the auto-complete function. I am using the latest version of emacs from from Cassou and have the code recommended in the tern-auto-complete.el in my .emacs. The auto-complete-functions are being called automatically, for example, when I type in the dot after Math. So, it is loaded.

Comment: `The auto-complete-functions are being called automatically, for example, when I type in the dot after Math. So, it is loaded.`, I am just guessing it seems you are using `ac-source-tern-completion` elsewhere, can you do `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` and post the traceback you get when the error occurs

Comment: Thank you. Will send the log. But before that, I have noticed that tern autocomplete works as expected with emacs-snapshot, while it does not work with the emacs24. I downloaded emacs-snapshot from ubuntu ppa.

Comment: Actually tern works for me on emacs 24.3, I am not sure what the problem might be maybe the log will make the issue clearer, lets see.

Comment: Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable ac-source-tern-completion)
  ac-source-available-p(ac-source-tern-completion)
  ac-compile-sources((ac-source-tern-completion ac-source-abbrev ac-source-dictionary ac-source-words-in-same-mode-buffers))
  ac-compiled-sources()
  ac-prefix(nil nil)
  ac-start()

Comment: This is only the part of the error log. The error log itself is very long and dense with the lisp code.

Comment: Hi, will it be possible for you to post the entire log, the part you have posted is actually too short to debug.